# Is my understanding of wordpress themes correct?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress theme for a website and would like to use wordpress as a CMS. I'm relatively new to wordpress development but am an experienced php developer coming from Zend Framework. Basically, I created a new theme and i've setup a home page in the admin tool. The site is pretty basic, with a header, content area, and footer that will be used on all pages. I designed the header and footer in the theme but when I got to the content section I began to ask myself some questions...

Basically, the question is whether or not it is considered correct to do:

```
<?php the_content(); ?>
```

or

```
<section id="home_page_content">
    <div class="home_left">
        <div class="main_image">
            <div class="mariela_circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home_right">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

</section>
```

The first seems to be more correct to me as I can simply take the markup from the second option and paste it into the wordpress editor for that page. I am also using a shortcode to help make editing the dynamic portions of the site easier. Here is what I ended up putting in the page editor using the admin tool for the home page:

```
<section id="home_page_content">
    <div class="home_left">
        <div class="main_image">
            <div class="mariela_circle"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home_right">
        [homePageSplash title1="Hello," title2="a bit about myself." content="a paragraph of text goes here." circle1Text="Item 1"]
    </div>
</section>
```

This works very well, but some of the markup here might be re-used on other pages. Let's say I create a second page. I might copy this entire block but just change the shortcode. I would rather not do this as I don't want to duplicate any code. In this case, would it be appropriate to create another shortcode to generate this markup and also call the shortcode I listed above? If anybody has experience doing this please share how you approached this problem. I want to make sure the process I am using is correct. Thanks!

Comment: btw. there is a specialized stackexchange site for wordpress: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ (Please don't cross post, but if you think it matches your question better than SO, you can flag for migration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use any markup in your text-editor, WordPress was build so even people with no HTML knowledge could use it so I would advise you do to the same. Only type your content in the text editor.

`the_content()` should be used inside "The Loop", a basic loop goes like this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php //use the_content() and similar functions (the_title()) here ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Read more: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to create a website where the owner can simply go into the content section and make edits. Imagine I have four sections in the content area which can all be editable by the site owner in the page editor. But the html of these sections will need to be created. Is there a way to create these four sections in the layout and then reference them in the content area? The only way i've found this to be possible is by creating a plug-in, which seems like overkill. A shortcode is a better approach in my opinion, but I have to create the markup in the editor...

Comment: You can create meta boxes for additional content areas, or you can use the Page.ly MultiEdit plugin.  The plugin is fantastic; however it still requires that you create your markup in a page template and add a couple other pieces of code as well.  Check it out here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pagely-multiedit/

Comment: Adding metaboxes seems like the way to go if you want the user to edit different parts of the same page. Read more about them here: [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

Comment: After experimenting with metaboxes this seems to be exactly what i'm looking for. I wanted to create sections inside the main content that are editable by the author. This will give the author a friendly and understandable interface that they can use to modify the content of the various sections on the main page. I'm surprised I didn't read about metaboxes earlier as they seem like an important part of wordpress development. Thanks again for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, yes, you are correct. There are a few adjustments or changes I would do, but I won't go into that as it is personal choice. I would recommend you [download some free Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) themes and reverse engineer them; i.e. pull them apart!

There are also [some good tutorials on themes](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_create_theme.htm). Wordpress is much the same as Joomla (in as far  as themes go) if you have ever used it.